# Javascript event handler on body but not on input

Tags: javascript

I have the following  event handler

`document.addEventListener('keydown', handleBodyKeyDown, false);`

HOW DO i prevent it from occurring when inside a input box

Comment: Are you really using jquery AND prototype AND dojo in your app? Did you expect a solution in plain Javascript or with one of the libraries?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Within your `handleBodyKeyDown` function, check if

```
 event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT'
```

(or `'TEXTAREA'`).

**Note:** For older versions of IE, use `event.srcElement.tagName`.

Like so:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleBodyKeyDown, false);

function handleBodyKeyDown(event)
{
    var e = event || window.event,
        target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') return;

    // Now continue with your function
}
```

---

P.S. Why are you using `addEventListener` if you have jQuery on the page? In jQuery, all of this gets sorted out for you:

```
$(document).on('keydown', ':not(input)', function(e)
{
    // Your code goes here...
});
```

Comment: Maybe use `e.target.matches('input')` for cleaner syntax?

Answer (score 2):

In your `handleBodyKeyDown` method, check to see if the event originated on an `input` element:

```
function handleBodyKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT') {
        return; // do nothing
    }

    // do the rest of your code
}
```

Note that the `toUpperCase` call is necessary because the conditions that determine the case of the `tagName` property are quite complicated and sometimes all but uncontrollable.

See [`event.target` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
const fromInput = event => event.srcElement instanceof HTMLInputElement;

function handleBodyKeyDown(event) {
  if(fromInput(event))
    return;
  
  // do your magic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jQuery` you can try this which uses `is()` method to test the target element is `input` then do nothing.

```
function handleBodyKeyDown(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is("input")) {
        return; 
    }
    else{
       //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
handleBodyKeyDown = function(e) {
   var e = e || window.event
   if (e.target.tagName != "INPUT") {
       // handle this since it isn't input
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (as to me) it is better not to prevent it to occur, but to ignore in the event cases, when it occured in the input. It's looks like this is also your case as well.

Just inspect `evt.target || evt.srcElement` property (modern frameworks do this normalization work for you, so, most probably this will be called target) whether it's input or not. If not, just ignore.

Answer (score 0):

[QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) tells you how to get an event's target.  You can check that it is not an input:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    if( targ.tagName != "INPUT" ) {
       //Perform your action here
    }
}
```

Your question is tagged jQuery, in which case you can just test event.target as the framework normalizes this for you.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function (event) {
    if(event.target.tagName != "INPUT") {
        //Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HandleBodyKeyDown function will be invoked in any case. You can not prevent its call on the method of recording as you indicated. You can only add a logic for checking if this an 'input' and return. Additionaly (if needed) you can prevent it from bubble up:

```
function handleBodyKeyDown(ev) {
  ev=ev||event;
  var sender=ev.target||ev.srcElement;
  if(sender.tagName.toLowerCase()==="input") {
    if(ev.stopPropagation)ev.stopPropagation();
    else ev.cancelBubble=true; // for IE8 or less
    return true; // do not prevent event from default action
  }
  // your code for global keydown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Prototype (which you have tagged but you also have two other frameworks tagged) then the event can be registered and filtered in one like this:

```
document.on('keydown', ':not(input)', handleBodyKeyDown);
```