# Get javascript keydown event only if not writing

Tags: javascript, keydown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript event handler on body but not on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230976/javascript-event-handler-on-body-but-not-on-input)

I wrote a short script that listens the keydown event, but i'd like to ignore it if i'm writing in a text field.

I have no idea about how to do it without strange tricks, like checking if there is a focus on one of the inputs.

Here is my code right now.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 71) {
        showSelected();
    }
    else if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        closeModal();
    }
});
```

Comment: A bad solution would be to add the keydown listener to all input fields and stop propagation. There should be a more clever solution.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230976/javascript-event-handler-on-body-but-not-on-input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little tricky if you're doing things with `contenteditable` (like letting users write text inside of any divs/spans/boxes they want to on the page).

If so, this will take a little thinking and reworking (it's not *that* hard - just more involved).

However, you can check the `event.target` (element the event's happening on) for its `tagName` property, against a list of types you want to exclude.

```
function keyEvent (evt) {
    var key = evt.keyCode,
        el = evt.target,
        type = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
        // tag names are upper-case... almost always...
        // so convert one way or the other, to be sure  
    if (type === "input" || type === "textarea") { return; }
    /* do whatever you were going to do */
}
```

Should also likely be noted that this solution (and your code thus-far) aren't ghetto-IE compatible.
For that, you'd need to work with `attachEvent` and the `window.event` and `window.event.srcElement` properties, because they don't support `addEventListener` and the `e`/`event` function-parameter.

Comment: One should not forget `select` elements et al. Effectively, I used `evt.target.matchesSelector("form *")` when I implemented such a feature.

Comment: You can check if it's a `contenteditable` element with `event.target.isContentEditable`.

Answer (score 1):

just check  for the `event.target`

```
{ 
   if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT') return false;

    // Do your Coding
}
```