# how to switch browser event target

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, events, three.js

I have a three.js based 3d scene which occupies the whole window.

I have angular load up a html overlay, which occupies a column of enarly 20% width on the right side.

I m using something similar to this to know where an event has occured
- [Javascript event handler on body but not on input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230976/javascript-event-handler-on-body-but-not-on-input)

Now the problem is after I click on a checkbox on the html overlay. Any future keyboard event (for e.g. w,a,s,d for moving the camera in my 3d scene) has target = input.

Even If I click on the 3d scene and initate keyboard event the target is input.

I have to remove the html overlay and then all future keyboard events have target body.

How do I allow the user to switch the event target without removing the html overlay?

Comment: It could be done by listening to the change in the checkbox and immediately bluring it. Just an idea, haven't done it.

Comment: Where is your code you have so far?

Comment: a simplified plnkr would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The target will be set to the currently focused element. All you have to do is make sure you blur the checkbox after you click on it. You can write an extremely simple directive to do this. For example:

```
app.directive("noFocus", function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.find("input").on("focus", function(ev) {
      ev.target.blur();
    });
  };
});
```

You can then use it on your html overlay:

```
 <div no-focus>
          Things inside here should lose focus immediately.

          Click Here: <input type="checkbox" />
          <p>
          After clicking on the checkbox it should still log the body as the target on keypresses.  
          </p>


    </div>
```

Here is a plunkr so you can see it in action, try clicking on the checkbox and then typing keys:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mzxjdBKfz59Ec0R9oq1K?p=preview

If you remove the "no-focus" directive it will log input to the console as you press the keys. If you have the "no-focus" it will log `<body>` even if you have clicked on the checkbox.